# How to programmatically compute the attribute names of HTML elements (directives) in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these attribute-restricted directives defined in AngularJS:

```
<div data-pie-chart data="..."></div>
<div data-line-chart data="..."></div>
<div data-column-chart data="..."></div>
```

When rendering the page, I load a list of charts from the server in JSON format, such as:

```
[ { chartType: "pie", data: [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ] },
  { chartType: "pie", data: [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] },
  { chartType: "pie", data: [ 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 ] },
  { chartType: "column", data: [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 ] },
  { chartType: "column", data: [ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ] } ]
```

I would like to use an **ng-repeat** (or similar) to generate the following code:

```
<div data-pie-chart data="[1,1,1,1,1]"></div>
<div data-pie-chart data="[2,2,2,2,2]"></div>
<div data-pie-chart data="[3,3,3,3,3]"></div>
<div data-column-chart data="[4,4,4,4,4]"></div>
<div data-column-chart data="[5,5,5,5,5]"></div>
```

I would like to have an elegant "angularish" code that is capable of doing this, ideally without leveraging "ng-switch" or "ng-if" because the list of charts is not limited and not known in the beginning (new types of charts can be added at anytime).

Can I compute the name of the atribute somehow? So that I don't need to hardcode all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similarly using an outer directive and an inner template.  The outer directive is responsible for compiling your inner chart directives once the type is known.

**wrapper directive**

```
.directive( 'chartWrapper', [ '$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        scope: { data: '=', type: '=' },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
            var dom = '<div ' + $scope.type + ' data="' + $scope.data + '"/>'
            var el = angular.element(dom)
            $compile(el)($scope)
            elem.append(el)

        }
    }
}])
```

I haven't tested this since it's a little different than my own case but should get your started.

Comment: It works like a charm, exactly as it is! Thank you very much!